# On my Surface RT/RT2, UpgradeToSslAsync is too slow on both Win8/Win8.1 via WiFi

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I am working on a project for Surface RT/RT2 and Surface Pro2. In my recent work, I found that `UpgradeToSslAsync` is too slow on Win8/Win8.1 on the devices. When I connect one of our company’s website with its FQDN (it is accessible from both intranet and Internet) within our intranet without any DNS/proxy configured, the issue occurs with a high probability.

Given this website is `xxx.a.com` with `https`. If I access it from IE, it is about 20~40 seconds to succeed. However, my program will take about 150 seconds to succeed.

My program follows [StreamSocket.UpgradeToSslAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.upgradetosslasync%28v=win.10%29.aspx) to make the connection. There are two steps: a) make a plain connection to `xxx.a.com` with `https`; After it succeeds, b) upgrade the connection to SSL.

Step a) is very fast, but the issue occurred at step b). It will wait more than 145 seconds before the completed event of `UpgradeToSslAsync` comes.

The issue doesn't occur each time. It maybe there or not after I reinstall my program or reboot the machine.

I don’t know why this happened. Would you please give me some suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry that I've missed something: we've implemented the classic BSD socket API with streamsocket, so in step a), we will get the IP of the website first, then make a plain connection to it; After it succeeds, we will do step b). Another point is that if we connect the website within an intranet environment, it works well. Thanks.